# Powershell Get-ADcomputer

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm current creating a tool to use to query AD with a GUI. I've got my other sections done for users and groups but computers is going to be difficult.

The only thing holding me back current is thr IPV4 and IPV6 portion of the filtering.

```
Get-ADcomputer -f {name -like $name -and IPV4address -eq $IPV4 -and IPV6addess -eq $ipv6} -properties *
```

I use a wildcard to fill Name but it won't allow me to fill IPV4 or ipv6 with wild cards. Is there a way around this? As I would like to be able to search for IPs and Name's together, as I can do partial of each.

Comment: I came with with a work around. And how my work's AD is set up AdComputer pulls IPs and ADobject does not. Which is strange. An Nslookup to grab the computer name and search by computer name is the workaround I came up with. Not ideal but it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with AD-cmdlets. Computer objects doesn't know or care about IP-addresses. That's the job of DNS.